# How to Center an Image

Tags: html, css

Currently I have an image saved in my project of a map that I would like to include in my solution, my first website. I'm very new to ASP.NET and CSS but have some HTML experience. I am having trouble figuring out how to center and stretch the image appropriately so that regardless of the size of the browser window, the center of the map always remains centered accordingly.

Please advise!

```
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="/img/additional/map.png"/>
        </div>            
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

EDIT 1:

I've found on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images the following information

Responsive images

Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

To center images which use the .img-responsive class, use .center-block instead of .text-center. See the helper classes section for more details about .center-block usage.

SVG images and IE 8-10

In Internet Explorer 8-10, SVG images with .img-responsive are disproportionately sized. To fix this, add width: 100% \9; where necessary. Bootstrap doesn't apply this automatically as it causes complications to other image formats.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Comment: Add `text-align: center;` or `margin: 0 auto` on image

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, a free bootstrap template downloaded actually.

Comment: use class `text-center` along with `row`.

Comment: You can use Center-block class as well.

Comment: Just div d-block and w-100 class to img. If you are using bootstrap 4

Comment: Or if you want center image in view port then give `d-block` and `mx-auto` class

Answer (score 3):

Added `class="img-responsive center-block"` according to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images .

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/img/additional/map.png"/>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply add center tag  to the image.

```
<section>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <center>
            <img src="/img/additional/map.png"/>
         </center>
      </div>            
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: <center> element is deprecated since HTML 4

Answer (score 1):

If are you using bootstrap, you can do it:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="..." class="rounded" alt="...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use pure CSS, for example:

.

```
center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add class center-block 
Ref : [here](http://code.makery.ch/library/more-html-css/image-bootstrap/)

e.g : `<img class="center-block" src="/img/additional/map.png"/>`

Comment: e.g : <img class="center-block" src="/img/additional/map.png"/>